# How to connect pgAdmin III (Windows) to postgresql (Linux in virtual box)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a `postgresql` demon on my virtual Linux box, and just installed pgAdmin III on the Windows machine. Now I'd like to configure the first connection.

What I did so far:

- I edited `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` and added a line to make the demon accept connections from my Windows machine:
  `host  all  all  192.168.123.45/32  md5`
- I set a shell passphrase for the system user `postgres` (`sudo passwd postgres`)
- **Edit: this seems to be irrelevant**
  I copied `/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/pg_service.conf.sample` to `/etc/postgresql-common/pg_service.conf` and uncommented the sample service, giving me
  [postgres]
  dbname=postgres
  user=postgres
- **Edit: this seems to be irrelevant**
  I put a line into `/etc/environment` to point to the `pgservice.conf` file:
  `PGSERVICEFILE=/etc/postgresql-common/pg_service.conf`
  (which works; when I duplicated the PuTTY session, it had this variable)
- I restarted the database server after each change:
  `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`
- Finally, I restartet the Linux box,

The server seems to have restarted successfully:

```
[ ok ] Restarting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server: main.
```

However, when I try to connect to the service, pgAdmin III gives me an error message:
Error connecting to the server: definition of service "postgres" not found.

`dmesg | grep postgres` gives me a single line:

```
[   18.054965] postgres (2242): /proc/2242/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/2242/oom_score_adj instead.
```

I have no clue whether `postgresql` uses my `pq_service.conf` at all, or whatever else is the problem; any help is appreciated ...

**Edit:**
My original question, "`How can I know whether postgresql uses my pg_service.conf file?`", seems to be answered - it simply doesn't.  I still can't connect; but now the question doesn't match the error messages anymore.

I removed the "Service" entry from my "New Server Registration" data. Now I get another error - something like "password authentication for user >>postgres<< failed". I'm quite sure the password is correct - I just set it ... and I tested it by commenting out my ssh key from the `authorized_keys` file.

I'd happily connect with my ssh key, but this seems to be difficult as well.  With PuTTY, my key is taken from Pageant, and I'm logged in without any problem; pgAdmin talks about "SSH tunnelling", but I normally don't need tunnels for this local machine ...

I tried to create a tunnel anyway.

- PuTTY session:

  - Source port is `5432`
  - destination is `my-vbox.host.name:5432`
- In pgAdmin, "SSH Tunnel":

  - Username `postgres`
  - using Identity file
  - Tunnel host `localhost` → error:
    "`SSH error: Could not connect to socket with error code 10051`"
  - Tunnel host `localhost:5432` → error:
    "`SSH error: Unable to resolve host: localhost:5432`"
  - Tunnel host `127.0.0.1:5432` → error:
    "`SSH error: Unable to resolve host: 127.0.0.1:5432`"

How the heck is this supposed to be configured?!

Comment: Actually `pg_service.conf` is a standard config file but for [`libpq`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgservice.html)-based clients. And has zero effect on the server side.

Comment: Thank you - I forgot about the "Service" and updated my question.

Comment: _and I tested it by commenting out my ssh key_: you're confusing the **password of the postgres database user** which is what the error is about, with **the password of the postgres linux user** which is relevant for ssh but not for the postgresql server.

Comment: Yes, but when in a shell as user `postgres`, psql won't ask further questions when I intend to act as database user `postgres`. When the system user `www-data` runs Zope, and the database user `www-data` owns the database, all I need to connect is the database name. Those two are different things, but connected.

Comment: @Tobias: it's the pg_hba.conf that controls all this. When you set `md5` as the auth method, you're telling that you want all users from 192.168.123.45 for all databases to provide a password. Replace it with `trust` to avoid the password if that's what is blocking you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to connect as db user `tobias` (I never had problems to connect locally, with `psql`).

```
# sudo -u postgres psql postgres
psql (9.1.9)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 tobias    | Superuser                                      | {}

postgres=# ALTER USER tobias WITH PASSWORD 's3cr3t';
ALTER ROLE
```

After doing this, I could connect as `tobias`, using the password just set.
The "Maintenance DB" happens to be `template1`; I didn't try to change this.

For further reference - I activated `log_connections` in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` and watched the log:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
```